# Regex to match @word

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to match words that start with @

```
var tag = comment.match(/(\b@\S+\b)/ig)
```

This is what I'm using as RegEx but it is not working. It works only with letters. How can I specify the character @?

Comment: Probably `/\B@\S+\b/g`

Comment: The specific issue here is that `\b@` will only match a word boundary of which `@` is the non-word character. The "word" starting with `@` is not all regex `word` (`\w`) characters.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thanks mate. It works